# Same Quantity Problem in List Item in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, flutter-listview, dio

```
body: BlocBuilder<AnasayfaCubit,List<Yemekler>>(
  builder: (context,yemeklerListesi){
    if(yemeklerListesi.isNotEmpty){
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: yemeklerListesi.length,//3
        itemBuilder: (context,indeks){//0,1,2
          var yemek = yemeklerListesi[indeks];
        
            
              child: Card(

                        
                             child:FloatingActionButton(
                                 onPressed: () {
                                   setState(() {


                                     simpleInput--;
                                   });
```

> How can I change the amount specifically for each item?  I am working  with Bloc Pattern and Json in Flutter.[image]  How is the arrangement made in the list for each element?

Comment: add details to your question what you want to achieve or what error are you facing.

Comment: I added image for output.The quantity is changing all the items in the list, I don't want that. I just want to change the quantity of a single item

Comment: can you provide the data of this list yemeklerListesi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like all the product widgets are reading the quantity from the same place `simpleInput`, best solution is to have the whole products widget as a stand-alone widget with its own state, where you can add and remove the quantity, so each product will have its own quantity counter.

Comment: I'm comming the data from Json. The JSON I get has the photo, the price, and the name.I'm converting it to a list.I'm also trying to add quantity.How should I handle only one item and not every item? I can not understand.

Comment: class Yemekler{
  String yemek_id;
  String yemek_adi;
  String yemek_resim_adi;
  String yemek_fiyat;

  Yemekler(
      {required this.yemek_id, required this.yemek_adi, required this.yemek_resim_adi, required this.yemek_fiyat});

  factory Yemekler.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return Yemekler(
      yemek_id: json["yemek_id"] as String,
      yemek_adi: json["yemek_adi"] as String,
      yemek_resim_adi: json["yemek_resim_adi"] as String,
      yemek_fiyat: json["yemek_fiyat"] as String,
    );
  }